# Mapbox title on markers always visible

Tags: mapbox

In mapbox, how can I show titles on markers? I want them to be always visible not on mousover or mouse click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `popup.addTo(map)` instead of `popup.openOn(map)`.

Also, you might want to address `closeOnClick` and `closeButton`.

```
var popup = L.popup({closeButton : false, closeOnClick : false})
    .setLatLng([tweet.y, tweet.x])  // Or something
    .setContent(html)
    .addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open marker popups programmatically using the `openPopup` method. Here's how you can do this with a bit of JavaScript, as well as a [live demo](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/open-popup-externally/).

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-zr0njcqy');

// wait until the markers are loaded, so we know that `map.markerLayer.eachLayer`
// will actually go over each marker
map.markerLayer.on('ready', function(e) {
    // when a user clicks the button run the `clickButton` function.
    // Thanks to function hoisting in Javascript, we can define the function
    // after we reference it here.
    document.getElementById('open-popup').onclick = clickButton;
});

function clickButton() {
    map.markerLayer.eachLayer(function(marker) {
        // you can replace this test for anything else, to choose the right
        // marker on which to open a popup. by default, popups are exclusive
        // so opening a new one will close all of the others.
        marker.openPopup();
    });
}
```