# Nativescript mapbox plugin , marker titles always visiable

Tags: javascript, mapbox, nativescript

I am using mapbox plug-in in my nativescript project. I have to show few markers on the map and I would like to set these titles to always visiable. Is there an easy way to do it on nativescript plug-in ?

```
args.map.addMarkers([
    {
        lat: 41.0063886,
        lng: 28.9781057,
        title: 'Area 1',
        subtitle: 'Something',
        onCalloutTap: function () {
            console.log("");
        },
    }
```

This is how I add a marker.

```
<ContentView height="320" width="320">
    <map:Mapbox
        accessToken=""
        mapStyle="light"
        latitude="41.01557434"
        longitude="28.9800726"
        zoomLevel="13"
        showUserLocation="true"
        mapReady="onMapReady">
    </map:Mapbox>
</ContentView>
```

and this is how I create the map.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of that plugin. There's no way AFAIK to make the callout appear without the user interacting with the marker. That's not a limitation of the plugin, rather the native SDK.. so your best option is to open a ticket on their GitHub and ask the same question (or refer to this SO question). https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/

Comment: That's for the JS SDK I guess

Comment: I saw this question, thats why I asked about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252330/mapbox-title-on-markers-always-visible